# Get the name of the changed attributes through Change Tracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

That's what I have:

```
var book = myContext.Books.Where(x =>x.ID = bookID).FirstOrDefault();

book.name = "New book name";
myContext.Update(book);

if (myContext.Entry(book).State == EntityState.Modified) {
  foreach(var entry in myContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()) {
    Console.WriteLine("Entity: {0},  State: {1} ", entry.Entity.GetType()., entry.State.ToString());
  }

  myContext.SaveChanges();
```

What I need is to know the name of the attribute that was changed (name). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible and you do it like this:

```
var modified = entry.Properties.Where(p=>p.IsModified);
foreach( var prop in modified )
{
       var name = prop.Metadata.Name;
}
```